# How does reminder operator works in Java (%) when the dividend is less than the divisor?

Tags: output, operators

I would like to know the specific reason why the following code returns the following output.

`int myReminder = 3%10; //note that the dividend (3) does not fit in the divisor(10);  System.out.println(myReminder);`

output: 3

Why does it returns me 3? I would like an specific reason, thank you!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so sometimes when dividing there is something left over. It is called the remainder.

- **Case 1: 21%10**. In this case, you can divide 21 into groups of 10 a maximum of 2 times. So there is a 1 left. So, that is the remainder.
- **Case 2: 3%10**. In this case, you can divide 3 into groups of 10 a maximum of 0 times, i.e., you cannot divide it. So, at the end you have 3 left as the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it like this: "3%10 == **3-3/10*3**"
First we divide: "3/10 = 0.<del>3</del>". Since we have int, everything after the dot is removed, so we get 0. 
Then we multiply the result of the division by 3: "0 * 3 = 0" 
Last goes the substraction: 3 - 0 = 3.